# Expression<Func<T, bool>> в LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Почему нельзя использовать Expression в методе Where?

```cs
Expression<Func<FormData, bool>> isAdult = form => form.Age >= 18;
// db - условная база с анкетами
IQueryable adult = db.FormData.Where(x => isAdult(x));
//--------------------------------------------^ CS0149: Method name expected
```

Для решения этой проблемы в сети предлагают использовать LinqKit и метод AsExpandable(), но объяснения, почему происходит ошибка компиляции, я не нашел.
Entity Framework 6, не Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IQueryable adult = db.FormData.Where(isAdult);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сложно передать эмоции, я довольно много времени потратил, чтобы разобраться, в чем причина